# obtener texto de una <a href> con onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente codigo genero un listado de PDF pero a este me gustaria darle la opcion de eliminar, para esto necesito obtener el nombre de archivo en este caso `File1.pdf` mediante la `onclick="delete_file(x)" como lo podria obtener? Para luego eliminarlo mediante`AJAX`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {});

function delete_file(x) {
  console.log($(x).parent().prev().find('.collapsible-header').text());
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/js/all.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
    <div class="media ml-3">
      <img class="d-flex mr-3 z-depth-1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/flat-sign-pdf-download-icon-260nw-1554245693.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h6 class="mt-0">
          <a href="#" class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">File1.pdf </a>
        </h6>
        <i class="fas fa-trash float-right ml-5 mr-5 red-text" onclick="delete_file(this)">xx</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
    <div class="media ml-3">
      <img class="d-flex mr-3 z-depth-1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/flat-sign-pdf-download-icon-260nw-1554245693.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h6 class="mt-0">
          <a href="#" class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">File2.pdf </a>
        </h6>
        <i class="fas fa-times float-right ml-5 mr-5 red-text" onclick="delete_file(this)">xx</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
    <div class="media ml-3">
      <img class="d-flex mr-3 z-depth-1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/flat-sign-pdf-download-icon-260nw-1554245693.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h6 class="mt-0">
          <a href="#" class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">File3.pdf </a>
        </h6>
        <i class="fas fa-times float-right ml-5 mr-5 red-text" onclick="delete_file(this)">xx</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo subiendo el DOM hasta el padre con `parent()` y de ahí buscar el elemento `a` con el método `find()` y obtener su `href` con el método `attr("href")` o su texto con `text()`

## ejemplo:

```js
function delete_file(x) {
     let el = $(x).parent().find("a");
     console.log(el.attr("href"), el.text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/js/all.min.js"></script>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
        <div class="media ml-3">
          <img class="-flex mr-3 z-depth-1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/flat-sign-pdf-download-icon-260nw-1554245693.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
          <div class="media-body">
            <h6 class="mt-0">
              <a href="#" class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">File1.pdf </a>
            </h6>
            <i class="fas fa-trash float-right ml-5 mr-5 red-text" onclick="delete_file(this)">xx</i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
        <div class="media ml-3">
          <img class="d-flex mr-3 z-depth-1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/flat-sign-pdf-download-icon-260nw-1554245693.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
          <div class="media-body">
            <h6 class="mt-0">
              <a href="#" class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">File2.pdf </a>
            </h6>
            <i class="fas fa-times float-right ml-5 mr-5 red-text" onclick="delete_file(this)">xx</i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
        <div class="media ml-3">
          <img class="d-flex mr-3 z-depth-1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/flat-sign-pdf-download-icon-260nw-1554245693.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
          <div class="media-body">
            <h6 class="mt-0">
              <a href="#" class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">File3.pdf </a>
            </h6>
            <i class="fas fa-times float-right ml-5 mr-5 red-text" onclick="delete_file(this)">xx</i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks my budda

Answer (score 2):

Te recomendaría que evites las funciones *in line*  como `onclick="delete_file(this)`, pues son una **mala práctica** hacer que el HTML sea totalmente dependiente del código Javascript.

Otra cosa que está dificultando el asunto es tener un `<i>` fuera de todo contenedor. Otra cosa es que las clases de borrado no son uniformes (en unos elementos usas `fa-trash` y en otro no ¿?).

Aquí he supuesto que el archivo debería borrarse al pulsar en las `xx` (eso es lo que se interpreta del código debido a la función *in line* que tienes ahí, si no es así el código se puede modificar.

El listener en este caso escuchará los clicks sobre las `xx` y obtendrá el valor que hay en el elemento `a` del `div` contenedor.

Quizá convendría organizar mejor el código, por ejemplo, puedes dar a cada `<i>` un `id` que sea el nombre del archivo y así lo obtendrías más directamente. Igualmente, convendría quizá tener una clase uniforme para escuchar las acciones de borrado de archivos. Eso ya quedaría bajo tu cuidado.

Otra cosa, `document.ready` está obsoleto desde jQuery 3, deberías usar `function` en su lugar, como se muestra en el ejemplo.

```js
$(function() {

  /*Listener de los elementos con las clases fa-trash y fa-times*/
  $(".fa-trash, .fa-times").click(function() {    
  /*Buscamos el padre y primer link en él*/
   var mFile= $(this).parent().find('a:first').text();
    console.log("Mandar a borrar: " + mFile);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
    <div class="media ml-3">
      <img class="d-flex mr-3 z-depth-1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/flat-sign-pdf-download-icon-260nw-1554245693.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h6 class="mt-0">
          <a href="#" class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">File1.pdf </a>
        </h6>
        <i class="fas fa-trash float-right ml-5 mr-5 red-text" >xx</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
    <div class="media ml-3">
      <img class="d-flex mr-3 z-depth-1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/flat-sign-pdf-download-icon-260nw-1554245693.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h6 class="mt-0">
          <a href="#" class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">File2.pdf </a>
        </h6>
        <i class="fas fa-times float-right ml-5 mr-5 red-text">xx</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
    <div class="media ml-3">
      <img class="d-flex mr-3 z-depth-1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/flat-sign-pdf-download-icon-260nw-1554245693.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h6 class="mt-0">
          <a href="#" class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">File3.pdf </a>
        </h6>
        <i class="fas fa-times float-right ml-5 mr-5 red-text">xx</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que navegar por los nodos, mediante `parent();` obtienes el nodo padre, después tienes que navegar hacia los hijos con el método `.children();`, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

});

function delete_file(x) {
  console.log($(x).parent().children().children()[0].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/js/all.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
    <div class="media ml-3">
      <img class="d-flex mr-3 z-depth-1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/flat-sign-pdf-download-icon-260nw-1554245693.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h6 class="mt-0">
          <a href="#" class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">File1.pdf </a>
        </h6>
        <i class="fas fa-trash float-right ml-5 mr-5 red-text" onclick="delete_file(this)">xx</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
    <div class="media ml-3">
      <img class="d-flex mr-3 z-depth-1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/flat-sign-pdf-download-icon-260nw-1554245693.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h6 class="mt-0">
          <a href="#" class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">File2.pdf </a>
        </h6>
        <i class="fas fa-times float-right ml-5 mr-5 red-text" onclick="delete_file(this)">xx</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
    <div class="media ml-3">
      <img class="d-flex mr-3 z-depth-1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/flat-sign-pdf-download-icon-260nw-1554245693.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h6 class="mt-0">
          <a href="#" class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">File3.pdf </a>
        </h6>
        <i class="fas fa-times float-right ml-5 mr-5 red-text" onclick="delete_file(this)">xx</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero prefiero obtener el nombre del archivo mediante el onclick

Comment: De este `onclick="delete_file(this)"` ??

Comment: Sii mediante esa funcion

Comment: Ya edite mi repsuesta. :D

Comment: Gracias funciona!

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer un cambio pequeño en tu codigo reemplazando:

```
console.log($(x).parent().prev().find('.collapsible-header').text());
```

por:

```
console.log($(x).parent().find('a.collapsible-header').text());
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {});

function delete_file(x) {
  console.log($(x).parent().find('a.collapsible-header').text());
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/js/all.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
    <div class="media ml-3">
      <img class="d-flex mr-3 z-depth-1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/flat-sign-pdf-download-icon-260nw-1554245693.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h6 class="mt-0">
          <a href="#" class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">File1.pdf </a>
        </h6>
        <i class="fas fa-trash float-right ml-5 mr-5 red-text" onclick="delete_file(this)">xx</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
    <div class="media ml-3">
      <img class="d-flex mr-3 z-depth-1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/flat-sign-pdf-download-icon-260nw-1554245693.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h6 class="mt-0">
          <a href="#" class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">File2.pdf </a>
        </h6>
        <i class="fas fa-times float-right ml-5 mr-5 red-text" onclick="delete_file(this)">xx</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
    <div class="media ml-3">
      <img class="d-flex mr-3 z-depth-1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/flat-sign-pdf-download-icon-260nw-1554245693.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h6 class="mt-0">
          <a href="#" class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">File3.pdf </a>
        </h6>
        <i class="fas fa-times float-right ml-5 mr-5 red-text" onclick="delete_file(this)">xx</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A lo que entendí esto te puede ayudar a resolver tu problema

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/js/all.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
    <div class="media ml-3">
      <img class="d-flex mr-3 z-depth-1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/flat-sign-pdf-download-icon-260nw-1554245693.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h6 class="mt-0">
          <a href="#" class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">File1.pdf </a>
          <a href="#" class = "Eliminar" id="File2.pdf">Eliminar</a>
        </h6>
        <i class="fas fa-trash float-right ml-5 mr-5 red-text" onclick="delete_file(this)">xx</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
    <div class="media ml-3">
      <img class="d-flex mr-3 z-depth-1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/flat-sign-pdf-download-icon-260nw-1554245693.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h6 class="mt-0">
          <a href="#" class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">File2.pdf </a>
          <a href="#" class = "Eliminar" id="File2.pdf">Eliminar</a>
        </h6>
        <i class="fas fa-times float-right ml-5 mr-5 red-text" onclick="delete_file(this)">xx</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
    <div class="media ml-3">
      <img class="d-flex mr-3 z-depth-1" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/flat-sign-pdf-download-icon-260nw-1554245693.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h6 class="mt-0">
          <a href="#" class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">File3.pdf </a>
          <a href="#" class = "Eliminar" id="File3.pdf">Eliminar</a>
        </h6>
        <i class="fas fa-times float-right ml-5 mr-5 red-text" onclick="delete_file(this)">xx</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".Eliminar").on("click",function(){
        var archivo = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(`Eliminar ${archivo}`); 
    });
});

</script>
```